# How to add image into sqlite in windows store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I would like to create an app for image processing using SQLite in windows store app. 
i'm trying to store image into SQLite  and retrieve image from SQLite. for storing image,i'm trying to convert image from xaml control image source to byte array,but not working,

Any suggestions,image to byte array convertion in windows store app?

Answer (score 0):

this code In JAVA but u can convert into C#

Creating a table with a BLOB column:

```
CREATE TABLE storedImages (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, myImage BLOB);
```

Downloading an image using HTTP and storing it in your table:

```
DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet("your image url");  
HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);  
if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {  
    HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();  
    if (entity != null) {  
    // insert to database  
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.ImageField, EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));  
    getContentResolver().insert(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.CONTENT_URI, values);  
 }
}
```

Loading the BLOB into an ImageView:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
byte[] bb = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.ImageField));
myImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length));
```

Edit:1

for more reference in c# please see below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196618/C-SQLite-Storing-Images

Comment: i want to store image from xaml image control into sqlite, in windows store app sqlite,there is not Blob type,i'm using byte[] type